# Is trajectory the same as an orbit?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, terminology

Is [trajectory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory) the same as an [orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit)?

I wanted to know about gravity assists, but most books I find are talking about different types of orbits and such.

Are they related?

Comment: I'd say an orbit is a periodic trajectory but a trajectory is not always an orbit.

Comment: I think part of the difficulty you have with finding useful material about gravity assist is that it's a very specialized technique (how many of us are working as astronavigators?) and that it is a hard problem that is usually tackled numerically as part of optimal spacecraft trajectory design. Look at this paper to get a feeling for what a real problem solving strategy for modern space missions looks like: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.1822.pdf

Comment: @CuriousOne Where do you think I should start if I want to look into this kind of material?

Comment: I think you should read a book like "Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students" by Howard Curtis, if you want to get a useful introduction to how space engineers use the basic technique. In practice it's all done numerically and with complex theoretical methods on the mathematical side of the problem, but I imagine you might enjoy a hands on approach more.

Comment: Most generally in dynamical systems and classical mechanics, an orbit is a trajectory and a trajectory is an orbit and both are synonyms for flows. Some authors may do as @BrandonEnright, but then note that a periodic orbit is a periodic periodic trajectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms trajectory and orbit both refer to the path of a body in space. Trajectory is commonly used in connection with projectiles and is often associated with paths of limited extent, i. e., paths having clearly identified initial and end points. Orbit is commonly used in connection with natural bodies (planets, moons, etc.) and is often associated with paths that are more or less indefinitely extended or of a repetitive character, like the orbit of the Moon around the Earth.

I did had an exact question few months back, but [this page from NASA](http://history.nasa.gov/conghand/traject.htm) provided good amount of information regarding trajectory and orbit.

Answer (score 0):

Nop!

The definition of an tridimensional trajectory, is the set of 3D points $(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ determinted by the parameter $t$. Which means, it's a function $\mathbf r(t)$, where $\mathbf r: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^3$. Of course we can generalize to the $n$-dimensional case: $\mathbf r: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbf r(t) = (x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_n(t))$. The parameter $t$ often is the time, but it shouldn't be restricted to that.

The definition of an orbit caused by a central force, is a trajectory expressed by the function: $\phi(r)$. Where $r$ is the distance which connects both objects and $\phi$ is the polar angle.

Notice: In an orbit, the function implies the motion is periodic, and limited to a plan. This is not a limitation since, in all central forces, the angular momentum of the system is conserved, which implies the movement is restricted to a plan, perpendicular to the direction of the angular momentum.

Comment: This answer is overly restrictive. Does the ISS orbit the Earth? It's orbit decays thanks to the Earth's atmosphere and precesses thanks to the Earth's equatorial bulge (and to higher order harmonics). Does the Moon orbit the Earth? The Sun's perturbations on the Moon's orbit are quite significant; the evection was known to the ancients. Does the Earth orbit the Sun? The other planets perturb the Earth's orbit. The orbit of the ISS, the Moon, and the Earth cannot be characterized by a simple potential function $\phi(r)$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is trajectory the same as an orbit?

Yes and no. For example, you will see many textbooks and papers use the term [hyperbolic orbit](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=hyperbolic+orbit). I use the term myself. On the other hand, the ballistic part of a weapon's flight from the gun (or missile silo) is called a ballistic trajectory rather than a ballistic orbit.

Answer (score 0):

An orbit is a special case of a trajectory. Any ballistic flight path is a trajectory (throwing a ball or firing a cannon) and an orbit is a special case where the trajectory does not intersect the locally dominant gravitational body - at least in the short term.